# Confirm regex for currency and dollar symbol

Tags: php, regex

I'm allowing currency, plus letting users enter a dollar symbol (which will be stripped later).

So far this seems to work, but I'd like to see if anyone can find an issue with it.

Formats Allowed

```
10
10.00
10.50
$10
$10.00
$10.50
```

Here's the regex

```
/^(\\$?($|[0-9]\d{0,2}))/
```

Comment: Hi @timgavin , I am using https://regex101.com/ site to test your regex and it gives me error.

Comment: Like as soon as I paste the regex provided by your it gives me an error saying the pattern isn't valid.

Comment: @zenwraight I had no idea that site existed! You were right, so I played around and came up with this, which *seems* to work. `^(\$|[0-9]\d{0,2})`

Comment: Cool, let me also play around with it and get back to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra escape `\` which is causing an error. So i'm answering assuming you meant this regex `^(\$?($|[0-9]\d{0,2}))`

Currently your regex has a few issues:
 - It accepts an empty string. I'd get rid of the `$|` in your innermost group.
 - It does not validate the cents correctly i.e it will accept the value. the `d{0,2}` tells me attempted to validate the cents. You aren't checking for the `.` to seperate cents from dollars. Even if you were, you are allowing values like $123.1 to slip through. because `d{0,2} allows 1 digit after the decimal (Not sure if you intended that)
 - It only grabs at most the first 3 numbers. So $12345 will match $123

Final regex is `^(\$?([0-9]*\.?\d{2}?)$)` [demo here](http://regexr.com/3gi1e)Then seems like it works fine.

Comment: @timgavin i rewrote my answer. I didn't clearly understand your question at first.

Comment: Using `{2}` doesn't validate a single number, such as `1`, or `7`, which I failed to put in my original question. Sorry about that. However, using `{0,2}` does. This seems to work: `^(\$?([0-9]*\.?\d{0,2}?)$)`